# REPLACE() function for HiveSQL, REGEXP_REPLACE() not working as intended

Tags: hive, hiveql

I run the following statement to replace the characters of ".." to ".":

```
CREATE TABLE TableA AS
SELECT Column1,
REGEXP_REPLACE(Column2, "..", ".") AS NewColumn
FROM TableB;
```

The result of NewColumn became ".......", what's wrong with the REGEXP_REPLACE() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what @mck proposed, you can use quantifier for repeating patterns

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Column2, "\\.{2}", ".")
```

Or if you want to replace 2 or more dots with single one:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Column2, "\\.{2,}", ".")
```

Answer (score 1):

`regexp_replace` expects a regex pattern. `.` means any character in regex, so all pairs of characters are replaced with a fullstop because you specified `..` as the regex pattern.

To prevent this, you can either escape the fullstop:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Column2, "\\.\\.", ".")
```

or use `replace`, which expects a string pattern:

```
REPLACE(Column2, "..", ".")
```